# How to prove in figure that $x=30^\circ$, where we know angles $36^\circ$, $24^\circ$ and $18^\circ$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle, quadrilateral

[image]

I know how to prove
$\sin(156^\circ−2x)\sin24^\circ\sin18^\circ\sin36^\circ = \sin(x)\sin(x)\sin(138^\circ−x)\sin(x−12^\circ) $ 
but if is it possible to prove  without trigonometry?

Comment: Simply arguing about triangles is not enough: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A%2BX%2BD%3D180%2C+24%2BC%2BX%3D180%2CB%2BC%2B36%3D180%2CD%2B18%2BE%3D180%2C+C%2BD%3D180)

Comment: But you missed one equation??

Comment: Show us the proof of the equation. Where did the $156^\circ,138^\circ,12^\circ$ come from?

Comment: If you were to choose a value of $x$ and construct the figure from the baseline, the four angles at the bottom determine the diagonals and sides. The intersection of those diagonals and sides determine the two top vertices, which in turn determines the top. Thus the size of the angle labeled $36^\circ$ would be set by your choice for $x$. Or vice versa, only the correct choice for $x$ would give you $36^\circ$. So even though just adding angles isn't sufficient to solve the problem, the problem is not underspecified.

Comment: Your drawing is really far from an actual picture...

Comment: @piteer I solved it by a bit of geometry and the rest is trigonometry.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg show your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometric solution:

[image]

In figure DF is parallel with BC and we have:

$\overset{\LARGE\frown}{FDI}=24\Rightarrow \overset{\LARGE\frown}{IF}=\overset{\LARGE\frown}{ID}=48$

$\overset{\LARGE\frown}{DH}=2\times 18=36 \Rightarrow \overset{\LARGE\frown}{IH}=\overset{\LARGE\frown}{DIH}-\overset{\LARGE\frown}{ID}=36-24=12$

$\rightarrow \overset{\LARGE\frown}{FH}-\overset{\LARGE\frown}{IH}=24-12=12$

$\overset{\LARGE\frown}{CDH}=24\times 2+18\times 2=84$

$\Rightarrow \overset{\LARGE\frown}{IH}=84-12=72$

Due to statement:

$\overset{\LARGE\frown}{HB}=\overset{\LARGE\frown}{ED}\Rightarrow \overset{\LARGE\frown}{BE}=\overset{\LARGE\frown}{HD}=12+24=36$

$\overset{\LARGE\frown}{CI}=24+48=72=\overset{\LARGE\frown}{IB}\Rightarrow \overset{\LARGE\frown}{CIB}=2\times 72=144$

$\overset{\LARGE\frown}{CDE}=\overset{\LARGE\frown}{BIC}-\overset{\LARGE\frown}{BE}=144-36=108$

$\overset{\LARGE\frown}{ED}=\overset{\LARGE\frown}{CDE}-\overset{\LARGE\frown}{CD}=108-48=60$

finally:

$$x=\frac {60}2=30$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ABCD$ be our quadrilateral,$\measuredangle BAC=\measuredangle ADC=x$, $\measuredangle ACB=36^{\circ},$

$\measuredangle BDC=18^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle CAD=24^{\circ}.$

Also, let $\Delta ABC\cong\Delta CB_1A$ such that $B$ and $B_1$ are placed in the same side respect to the line $AC$.

Let $B_1C\cap BD=\{K\}.$

Thus, since $\measuredangle KCA=\measuredangle KDA=x,$ we see that $AKCD$ is cyclic, which gives $$\measuredangle B_1AK=\measuredangle KAC=18^{\circ}$$ and we obtain:
$$\frac{AB_1}{AC}=\frac{B_1K}{KC}$$ or
$$\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{AB-KC}{KC}$$ or
$$\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{AB}{BC}\cdot\frac{BC}{KC}-1$$ or
$$\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin(144-x)}=\frac{\sin36^{\circ}}{\sin{x}}\cdot\frac{\sin24^{\circ}}{\sin(x-12^{\circ})}-1$$ or
$$\frac{\cos12^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}}{\cos12^{\circ}-\cos(2x-12^{\circ})}-1=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin(x+36^{\circ})}$$ or
$$\frac{\cos\left(2x-12^{\circ}\right)-\frac{1}{2}}{\cos12^{\circ}-\cos(2x-12^{\circ})}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin(x+36^{\circ})}$$ or
$$\sin(3x+24^{\circ})+\sin(48^{\circ}-x)-\sin(x+36^{\circ})=$$
$$=2\sin{x}\cos12^{\circ}-\sin(3x-12^{\circ})+\sin(x-12^{\circ})$$ or
$$2\sin(x-6^{\circ})\cos(2x+30^{\circ})+2\cos18^{\circ}\sin(30^{\circ}-x)=2\sin{x}\cos12^{\circ}-\sin(3x-12^{\circ})$$ or
$$2\sin(30^{\circ}-x)(2\sin(x-6^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ}-x)+\cos18^{\circ})=$$
$$=\cos12^{\circ}(4\sin^3x-\sin{x})+\sin12^{\circ}(4\cos^3x-3\cos{x})$$ or
$$2\sin(30^{\circ}-x)(2\sin(x-6^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ}-x)+\cos18^{\circ})=$$
$$=\cos12^{\circ}\sin{x}(4\sin^2x-1)-\sin12^{\circ}\cos{x}(4\sin^2x-1)$$ or
$$\sin(30^{\circ}-x)(2\sin(x-6^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ}-x)+\cos18^{\circ})=\sin(x-12^{\circ})(1-2\cos2x)$$ or
$$\sin(30^{\circ}-x)(2\sin(x-6^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ}-x)+\cos18^{\circ})+2\sin(x-12^{\circ})\sin(30^{\circ}-x)\sin(30^{\circ}+x)=0$$ or
$$\sin(30^{\circ}-x)(2\sin(x-6^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ}-x)+\cos18^{\circ}+2\sin(x-12^{\circ})\sin(30^{\circ}+x))=0,$$ which gives $x=30^{\circ}$ because $12^{\circ}<x<78^{\circ}$ or
$$2\sin(x-6^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ}-x)+\cos18^{\circ}+2\sin(x-12^{\circ})\sin(30^{\circ}+x)=0,$$ which is
$$\cos18^{\circ}+\sin24^{\circ}+\sin(2x-36^{\circ})+\cos42^{\circ}-\cos(2x+18^{\circ})=0$$ or
$$\cos18^{\circ}+\sin24^{\circ}+\cos42^{\circ}=\sin(72^{\circ}-2x)-\sin(2x-36^{\circ})$$ or
$$\sin(54^{\circ}-2x)=\frac{\cos18^{\circ}+\sin24^{\circ}+\cos42^{\circ}}{2\cos18^{\circ}},$$ which is impossible because:
$$\frac{\cos18^{\circ}+\sin24^{\circ}+\cos42^{\circ}}{2\cos18^{\circ}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos66^{\circ}+\cos42^{\circ}}{2\cos18^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\cos54^{\circ}\cdot\frac{\cos12^{\circ}}{\cos18^{\circ}}>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot1=1.$$